# Visual Studio 2013 slow switch between browser and VS

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2013

I have a very annoying problem with Visual Studio 2013. I start my project website locally, do something on it (refresh, redirect or some other action), immediately go to Visual Studio, to do some changes and this switching between Browser and VS takes around 10 seconds, sometimes VS - Not Responding.

I've already read to uncheck somethings from *Tools* → *Options*, but without any success. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I believe that happens when you have exceptions in debug mode. Or when you have watch / break points. Are you sure you have none of those?

Comment: Thanks for the replay. It doesn't metter which page I've start, so there is no break points, the bebug mode is stoped, or if it start it is the same. 

I click F5 to refresh, if I open the Visual Studio before the refresh stoped, it open the VS fast, but at the moment the refresh stoped, the open VS not responding for several seconds. I've restart computer, stop other programs, read, change some settings... and nothing...